# Intuition of convex combination of probability measures.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, finance

In the paper Risk Preferences and their Robust Representation by S. Drapeau and M. Kupper, the authors say that if $\mu$ and $\nu$ are probability distributions (commonly referred as **lotteries**) on $ (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$, a convex combination of the two such as $\lambda \mu + (1- \lambda) \nu$ can be interpreted as **some additional randomization, since it corresponds to the sampling of either the lottery $\mu$ or $\nu$ depending on the outcome of a binary lottery with probability $\lambda$ or 1 - $\lambda$.**

I am confused by this interpretation, indeed I understand that, if $A$ is a set in $\mathcal{B}$ the definition is $$ (\lambda \mu + (1-\lambda) \nu) (A)= \lambda \mu(A) + (1-\lambda) \nu (A), $$
thus my natural intuition on this is that we are deciding to which probability give the most relevance.

Can somebody explain to me, perhaps with an example, why my interpretation of this is not the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X,Z$ be random variables on $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$. Let $Z\sim \textrm{Bernoulli}(\lambda)$. The above convex combination has the following probabilistic interpretation: for $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$
$$P(X\in A)=\underbrace{P(X \in A|Z=1)}_{\mu(A)}\underbrace{P(Z=1)}_{\lambda}+\underbrace{P(X\in A|Z=0)}_{\nu(A)}\underbrace{P(Z=0)}_{1-\lambda}$$
Therefore the unconditional law $P_X(A):=P(X \in A)$ is obtained by specifying first the conditional laws of $X$ on the random variable $Z$. It is not false that we are deciding to which probability we give more relevance: by Bayes for fixed non $P_X,\mu,\nu$-null $A$ and known $\mu,\nu$ we have
$$P(Z=1|X\in A)\propto\mu(A)\lambda,\quad P(Z=0|X\in A)\propto\nu(A)(1-\lambda)$$
So that conditional on $X$, higher $\lambda$ means more probability of having the $\{Z=1\}$ latent state for given $A$ (and less probability of having the other latent state).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am sorry but I don't understand the meaning of your answer. Who is X in my situation? Is $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ a generic probability space?

Comment: @leobgg you're welcome. Hope I will clarify: $X$ is whatever you are modelling that takes values on the real line. In your context it is probably portfolio loss. Its law will be on the real line, but its original space (what it maps from) is an arbitrary probability space. $Z$ will be a possibly unobserved state variable. Informally, this state variable determines which conditional law between $\mu$ and $\nu$ we draw $X$ from.

Comment: Ok thank you, I think I understand what you mean. You are saying that I should shift the focus. I want to study a random variable $X$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ which is usually a portfolio loss but I do not know anything about $P( X \in A)$. You just showed me that $P( X \in A) = \mu(A) \lambda + \nu(A) (1-\lambda)$ where $\mu$ and $\nu$ measure  on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$. Thus the initial thought should be "I don't know $P_{X}$ but if I condition X with a coin toss Z I can study it by studying all the convex combination of probability measure".

Comment: And then when the authors talk about \textbf{an additional randomization} they are not referring to $\mu$ and $\nu$ but to $X$. Am I correct?

Comment: @leobgg in my understanding, the additional randomization is given by $Z$, which describes a latent state in this interpretation (which is standard in finance) in this model. The 'standard' randomness, to which $Z$ adds to, is given by our variable of interest $X$

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification. May I ask you for a reference in which this interpretation you are talking about is described and formalized? I don't know If such reference exists but if it does It would be very helpful for me.

Comment: @leobgg more complicated models have been formalized, of which this one is a semplification/special case. Look up Gaussian HMM models and mixture models for asset returns for some introductory ones

Answer (score 0):

What it means is that with probability $\lambda$, you perform experiment $\mu$, and with probability $1 - \lambda$ you perform experiment $\nu$.

To get a sample $X$ from $\lambda \mu + (1 - \lambda)\nu$, first generate $U \sim Ber(\lambda)$, and then if $U = 1$ let $X$ be a sample from $\mu$, otherwise let $X$ be a sample from $\nu$. This is an instance of composing stochastic kernels. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_kernel. This is the formalism for "multistage experiments", where we specify only the conditional distributions and from these obtain a unique joint distribution.

Comment: Hello @Mason, this is correct but the context here is not experimental, but rather, as I could infer from the OP, a financial/insurance modelling issue. In fact in this framework there is no experimental agency (unless we specifically talk about behavioral economics)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. At first I myself thought about your interpretation but to me it does not match at all the definition. That it because every event $A$ is subject to both the experiment thus we don't choose $\mu$ or $\nu$ but, as I said previously, we just "weight" those and in a certain way choose which probability we consider more "correct".