Can Aggregating Normalized Count Vectors by Component-Wise Addition Be Modeled as Sum of Random Variables?
Suppose I have two count vectors $ \mathbf{X} = (X_1, X_2, \dots, X_C) $ and $ \mathbf{Y} = (Y_1, Y_2, \dots, Y_C) $. I model each as a probability distribution by normalizing them:
$$
\mathbf{p} = \frac{\mathbf{X}}{\sum_{i=1}^{C} X_i} \quad \text{and} \quad \mathbf{q} = \frac{\mathbf{Y}}{\sum_{i=1}^{C} Y_i}
$$
Next, I add the vectors component-wise to obtain $$ \mathbf{Z} = \mathbf{X} + \mathbf{Y} $$ and normalize $ \mathbf{Z} $ to get a new distribution:
$
\mathbf{r} = \frac{\mathbf{Z}}{\sum_{i=1}^{C} Z_i}
$
If assume that that $ \mathbf{X}$ and $ \mathbf{Y}$ are independent, does the normalization step makes them dependent?

I believe that the process you described is essentially a convex combination between two distributions (which is, in fact, another distribution). By scaling $\bf X$ and $\bf Y $ differently you get different convex combinations. However, the intuition behind the process is not the sum of two r.v.'s (that would be convolution), but a "randomization" between the two. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4470198/intuition-of-convex-combination-of-probability-measures for reference.

But I need it to describe it  as sum of random variables, since I want to apply something. Can one not somehow define that the summed   $Z$ is a random vector where the sum of counts for each component i occurs with probability $r_i$.

Even if you defined $Z$ that way, it wouldn't be the case that $Z=X+Y$. What is it that you would want to achieve by expressing $Z$ as sum of two r.v.'s?
